# Symfony slow download page

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have project with
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.11",
and when I open page all entity(in my situation developer) I use standart doctrine fincrion

```
$all_developer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->findAll();
    public function findAll()
{
    return $this->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'ASC'));
}
```

I wait 4 minutes open page and in debug panel I see download 103mb o_O this is nearly 4000 entity

**UPDATE**
I install DebeshaDoctrineProfileExtraBundle and I see with my entity developer I load table TalentFiles in this table I have file doc docx pdf how to disable this table when I find all develoeprs?

```
1   10.54 ms    1   SimpleObjectHydrator    

r => Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users

2   63.57 ms    100     ObjectHydrator  

r => Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer
e0 => Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\TalentFiles
```

I visible for you only field with relationship because I think maybe this is problem for download, when I find Developer doctrine find al entity in relationship. How to exclude all relationship and find all entity without this fields (who have realationship) If use Query Builder how to exclude???
this is my entity:

```
    public function getDevelopers()
{

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')
        //how to exclude???

        ->getQuery();
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Entity Developers and relationship

```
/**
 * Developers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="developers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\DeveloperRepository")
 */
 class Developer extends CustomUser
 {
///////////other field, I visible for you only field with relation ship

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TalentFiles", mappedBy="developer", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $talent_file;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeUserReference", mappedBy="developer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $reference_developer;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeProjectNotificationLater", mappedBy="developer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
public $notification_later;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teams", inversedBy="developers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
protected $teams;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeTalentsProjects", mappedBy="authorId", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $projects;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="talent", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
public $comment;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="add_developer")
 */
protected $added_by;
```

And some interesting - when I open home page with first page, this page have routing in another action and some information for entity admin thats all, without any entity I wait 15 - 40 second ans download 15-28mb o_0

In frontend I use metronic admin bundle maybe this information help

I add some screen in debug panel maybe this help for diagnostic problem
[link](http://uploads.ru/lDIau.png),[link](http://uploads.ru/JQArn.png),[link](http://uploads.ru/AROPz.png),[link](http://uploads.ru/ydx2P.png).Help please, maybe some people have this problem ??

Comment: Why you want to display all 4k entities in one page?

Comment: I want to display one entity getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->findAll()

Comment: I understund - I have pagination in fronted in table help with js

Comment: First of all, this is not download, it's PHP memory usage, secondly if you put all 4k entites in html and later you sort it with js, don't be surprised. Use pagerfanta, knp paginator or something. What happend if you'll have 6millions entities?

Comment: I know this bundle, but client want search with js and I need optimization selection, How to exclude all relationship and find all entity without this fields (who have realationship) If use Query Builder how to exclude??? I update my question

Comment: After you sort the server-side issues you'll need to use a virtualized list to display those 4k records.

Comment: how to exclude in DOCTRINE another table??